# Faster way to create an array of numbers spanning a range in Swift

Tags: swift

Is there a shorter way to create an array of numbers spanning a range in swift?

Right now, I'm using this:

```
var arrayOfInts = [UInt32]()

for number in 1...100 {
    arrayOfInts.append(number)
}
```

Is there a one-line way of doing it?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1690136-subscript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var arrayOfInts  = Array(1...100)
```

**Playground Output**
[image: playground]

Answer (score 2):

Is this short enough?

```
let array = Array(1...100)
```

Comment: Dave! Thank you so much. Sasquatch beat you by a hair. Hopefully, that's the only time Sasquatch is faster than you :)

Comment: Haha. Bravo. If programming doesn't work out, you should try comedy. 

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
var z = [Int](1...100)
print(z)
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/58a27d069024df34e9c9b1e1)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, Anik! That Swift sandbox is VERY cool!